# Azimuthal projection with d3.v3.js does not work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been trying to get an azimuthal D3 spinny globe script to work with D3.v3.js. I understand v3 has implemented some important changes and I have tried to implement these in my script but with no success. [Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px89d3eg/)

This is how I now define my projection:

```
var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
  .scale(380)
  .centre([-71.03, 42.37])
  .mode("orthographic")
  .translate([400, 400]);
```

I have tried to make a number of changes but cannot get the script to work. I understand certain functions have now been deprecated, including `d3.geo.greatCircle()` which is `now d3.geo.circle()`

Is there something I am not doing right? I have spent so much time trying to sort this out I might actually forget about upgrading to v3. Why release a new version which is seems to be incompatible with preceding versions?

Comment: There are many errors which are easy to spot, if you bother to check the console's output and read the API docs. E.g., it's `.center()`, not `.centre()`; there is no method `.mode()` on a projection; there is no `projection.origin()`. I suggest you sort these easily fixable things out and report back, should there be any issue left.

Comment: Also, and perhaps even more important, you might want to have a closer look at D3's version history since you are talking about *upgrading* to v3! This version is no longer supported, the new version is v4! If you really want to upgrade, check, if you want to go to v4 instead.

Comment: v3 is an upgrade from v2. I have not exlpored v4 yet. What am I to replace `projection.origin()` with?

Comment: I can't even find docs to tell me what that method might have done in v2. If it's not for educational purposes, to fulfill some occult customer needs or for the pure joy of pain, I'd waste no time in this upgrade. You'll have to find information for both versions anyway, why not step up to v4? So, unfortunately, you have already lost me on the way.